# ion side menu, make it update once content change

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an app made with ionic-framework.

I have a button that makes a user follow another user. The button posts to the API and it saves.

In the ion side menu, I list all the people I follow, which I get from the same API.

However, when I follow another user, the ion side menu doesn't update as it is cached I suppose. How do I make it update once I follow another user?

Thank you.

**Users profile controller**

```
$scope.toggleFollow = function(bool)
{
   $http.post('http://localhost:26264/api/follow?userId=' +$stateParams.userId +"&toggleFollow=" +bool);
}
```

**Left menu controller**

```
 $http.get('http://localhost:26264/api/follow').then(function(resp) {
    console.log('Success', resp);
    $scope.alternatives = resp.data;
```

Then I just loop out the $scope.alternatives in the left menu like

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="alternative in alternatives" href="#/app/user/{{ alternative.id }}">
      {{alternative.name}}
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I don't know how much code is needed to help, however, I'll add some code if it might help. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: I think you need to make call to `http://localhost:26264/api/follow` get when post has been successful in-order update follow count

Comment: Yes I understand that @pankajparkar, the problem is how would I do it? How do I update a view from another view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update  **$scope.alternatives**

For that, as we don't know your logic and code.

You can do the following :

**Solution 1: Creating an event emiter & receiver :**

From first controller : you can `$rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent",{info : myNewAlternativesInfo});`
From Second Controller : `$scope.$on("myEvent",args){ //update as needed alternatives with access to args.info`

**Solution 2: access to data from a service**

Both controller update and access to values from a shared Service
Then you just need to add on your second controller a watcher on the desired value to check when it updated `$scope.$watcher`

If that's not enough to lead you to solution, gives us more info ;)